What happens with direct electron-muon couplings?
Checking Peskin's Intro to QFT book, I found the following mantra, when talking about the interaction Hamiltonian $H_I$ obtained throught the expression $\langle\mu^+\mu^-|H_I|e^+e^-\rangle$:

our interaction Hamiltonian couples electrons to muons only through the electromagnetic field.

That implies that the matrix element $\langle\mu^+\mu^-|H_I|e^+e^-\rangle$ vanishes. I have seen similar results in other contexts for perturbative Hamiltonians, but what happens to the matrix element that equals zero? Is there a parity conservation for the coupled fermions' eigenfunctions that helps us obtain that zero, or is the Hamiltonian $H_I$ responsible for the nullification? Or is it just an experimental result that we're supposed to assume is true?
